# Ad failed to load: 3

Tags: java, android-studio, admob

Good afternoon, I am try to implement ads in my application but my real AD does not appear, only test AD, in the admob tab it appears that more than 300 requests were made, and there is no ads in the application. Is it necessary for me to publish my app in the play store so that the ads start to appear? And my account has been verified for a long time. In my Logcat appear this error Ad failed to load: 3, what i needed to do , to the ads start to showing?
[page admob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKTSF.png)

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFSVQ.png)

Answer (score 5):

As per the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL) you are getting the following error code:

> **public static final int ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL**
>
> The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of
> ad inventory.
>
> Constant Value: 3

> If you are getting this error, then your code is correct. The issue is
> that AdMob does not always have an ad to return for every request.
> This may happen particularly if you have just registered your AdMob
> publisher ID, as it takes some time and multiple requests before the
> new ID starts returning ads.
>
> I also faced the same issue. My app was showing test ads, but not real one.
> In my case ads started showing up when I uploaded my app to Google Play.
>
> To confirm your app shows ads correctly, you may first add your app to test tracks first.

Comment: Cannot see ads on test ids as well. giving the same error.

Comment: Can I know if you have created the ads in AdMob recently ?

Comment: What do you mean by created ads?

Comment: Hey @ParthAnjaria, did you happen to find anything?

Comment: No, the issue still persists

Comment: any solution please

Answer (score 4):

Error code 3 means your implementation is correct but your app is not approved by google admob,so you have to submit your app for approval, once your app is approved than  your app will start receiving ad after 24 hrs and you have to setup your payment method in google admob.

you can submit your app through this link for approval:
https://support.google.com/admob/contact/android_APK_submission?hl=en

Comment: in the** URL to download your APK file** field, should I put the Google Play URL or direct link to download the APK ?  thank you

Comment: you can put direct play store apk url.

Comment: Hi, google replied? Is it solved. Please share any update.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using app-ads.txt for your app, then you also have to include this line in your app-ads.txt file in order to load ads using the demo ad units:

```
google.com, pub-3940256099942544, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
```

Here the official Google AdMob reference: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Answer (score 0):

It shows when your device is not connected with Test Mode in your AdMob account. Connect your device with test mode and try this error will resolve.

https://apps.admob.com/v2/settings/test-devices/list?_ga=2.248138183.156733708.1671428691-2046682952.1670650994&_gac=1.127285631.1670650998.Cj0KCQiA1sucBhDgARIsAFoytUvUl2cXmiqt4eGOJlPz7EOFYJxnbpcLX3uIEhk71c3oHZ3BxMsgBE0aAlkcEALw_wcB&_gl=1*1ubza84*_ga*MjA0NjY4Mjk1Mi4xNjcwNjUwOTk0*_ga_6R1K8XRD9P*MTY3MTQyODY5MS40LjAuMTY3MTQyODY5MS4wLjAuMA..